# Why perl cgi does not compile CPAN module

Tags: perl, module, cgi, perl-module, cpan

My OS is Debian Buster. My cgi-bin is in /var. The CPAN module is HTML::Template and located in /perl5/lib/perl5/HTML as installed by cpanm. My server is Apache2 and appears to be configured correctly by all the research I have done (but something must be wrong somewhere). My browser is Firefox , but I also use curl for testing. I can run cgi perl scripts without perl modules from localhost/cgi-bin/ successfully. I can run perl scripts WITH 'use HTML::Template' from the command line with ./ with perfect HTML output BUT, AND THIS IS THE PROBLEM I cannot run these from localhost either with the browser or curl when they include a perl module such as HTML::Template.

The Apache2 error message is 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/cgi-bin/templateOne.cgi line 5.: /var/cgi-bin/templateOne.cgi
[Wed Oct 16 00:01:23.341309 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 3743] [client ::1:36728] End of script output before headers: templateOne.cgi

Now line 5 of the script is 
use HTML::Template;

So it fails to either locate or compile the module, but since the program works perfectly from the command line then Apache2 I assume is unable to locate the module.

I have tried using 
push(@INC, '//Perl5/lib/perl5/HTML');
at the start of the script but this does not work either.

Does any one have a suggestion

Comment: It is likely in your home directory, not `perl5` in the root directory. File paths are also case sensitive. It also looks up based on the whole module name so the library path you are actually looking for is `/home/youruser/perl5/lib/perl5`.

Comment: Do not update `@INC` manually, use [lib](https://perldoc.pl/lib) or you will not get version and arch specific instllations (such as XS code).

Comment: You can also use [SetEnv](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) to add the directory to the `PERL5LIB` environment variable for CGI scripts.

Comment: `BEGIN failed--compilation aborted` is never the first error message; what error are you actually getting?

Comment: `push(@INC, '//Perl5/lib/perl5/HTML')` should be `use lib '/perl5/lib/perl5';` You might be modifying `@INC` too late --`use lib` will change it at compile-time -- you misspelled `perl5`, and you shouldn't have included `HTML`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for those who provided comments. I have used the advice given by Grinnz who pointed me to the use of 'use lib /path /to /module'
By using the use lib statement with the path to the Template module as the second line of the script and before the use HTML::Template statement, the script worked perfectly.
Thanks again.